# Meteor: Adding sortable with rubaxa:sortable package

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, meteor

I try to integrate `rubaxa:sortable` to make my list sortable.

**client/helpers.js**

```
Template.getElements.helpers({
    children: function() { 
       return Articles.find({ parent: this._id }, {sort: {order: 1}}); 
    }
});
```

**server/publications.js**

```
Meteor.publish('articles', function() { return Articles.find({}, {sort: {slug: 1}}); });
Sortable.collections = 'articles';
```

**template**

```
<template name="getElements">
    <ul class="sortable">
        {{#each children}}
            {{#sortable items=Articles sortField="order"}}
                <li data-id="{{_id}}"><input type="text" name="keyword" value="{{title}}"></li>
            {{/sortable}}
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

In the documentation (https://atmospherejs.com/rubaxa/sortable) I see the info:

```
Client:

{{#sortable items=<collection|cursor|array> sortField="order"}}

Server:

Sortable.collections = <collectionName>;  // the name, not the variable
```

So what am I doing wrong? Right now no list-element is beeing shown.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert but based on integration this will fix your issues.

1. Server JS
   Update the declaration to include the collation name in [].

   **Sortable.collections = ['articles'];**
2. HTML Template
   remove the following:

   {{#each children}}

   {{/each}}

Regards,
Vince

Comment: I can't remove the {{each}} as this builds the list itself.